# flyout menu won't open in chrome or ie

Tags: flyout

I have a drop menu menu that works correctly in firefox but will not flyout in chrome or ie.  Is there some piece of code that can be added that will make it compatible in ie and chrome?

Thank you

Comment: Show your code? What does the console show in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Todd, Welcome to stackoverflow. In order for people on here to be able to take there own time out to help you and to assist you further you really do need to put that little bit more effort into the questions you ask. We are all here to help and in fact im still learning the very basics however im willing to take my own time to help you and others would do too if you could be specific with your question on here and more than likely people will able to assist.

What sort of "drop down menu" is this as you have said it is a "flyout menu" and to be honest when being specific a (flyout menu) is different to a (drop down menu).

- 1. Where did you get the original code?
  2. What language is this code in?
  3. Can you provide links or screen shots?
  4. Can you provide the code?
  5. what sort or error is occurring?
  6. what makes firefox so special that its the only browser to work in
     this occasion?

The only way i can help you and provide advice is if you put just as much effort in with your question and provide as much as possible, The more information you provide the more chance you have of having the problem solved first time round because more people reading your question will understand what your trying to do.. The broader the question the more answers available and therefore causes confusion. Everyone needs to be reading off the same page when trying to solve a problem and in this case its almost impossible to help you.

Also Todd, This is not an answer by any way of imagination. However this is the only way i can reply to your question due to having to build my profile to the required level of 50 in order to comment on such questions. However once you can provide more information or as much as you can provide i would be willing to do the best i can and edit this answer to be more relevant to your question and therefore hopefully solve the problem.

Here is a flyout menu example i found from a quick search:  http://jc-designs.net/demo/flyout.html#

And one here with drop down menus:  http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

If your certain as to the menu type and style you have then let us know as much about it as possible, just in case you got mixed up between the two as fly out menus can list there menu downwards but is still classed as a fly out and not a drop down.

Ill be waiting for the updated question ready to update my answer accordingly, Thanks.